# How to Pass Chat from Amazon Lex to Amazon Connect? e.g. Talk to agent intent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect, aws-chatbot

I have added an intent `TalkToAgent` in my Lex bot, i want to route the chat to agent on fulfillment of `TalkToAgent` intent. Is there any why i can achieve it? e.g. `Amazon Lambda`?
I just want to pass the chat to agent when customer wants to talk to a `human/agent.`

The goal is to transfer the chat with `history/transcript` to agent as agent can understand it what customer is looking for! chat is originating from lex. the same way it is being handled in `Amazon Connect`.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you please update your question to indicate if the chat is originating in an Amazon Connect contact flow or if the original chat is direct to lex from other app (website, slack, etc.)?  Also, do you need the agent to see the history/transcript form the bot chat prior to reaching the agent?

Comment: i just want to transfer the chat to agent with history/transcript. chat is originating from lex.